# Is there a way to debug the webpack compile process?

Tags: webpack, webstorm

I want check what's going on while webpack build something.

For example, I set some break points in `file-loader/index.js`. I want it can be stopped there, so that I can check the variables, paths, contexts, filenames, etc. is ok.

I am using WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Node debug configuration Webstorm that runs Webpack.

The settings for `JavaScript file` will be `node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js` and the `Application parameters` will be something like `--config webpack.config.js`. By default Webstorm will ignore all files in the `node_modules` folder but you can changes this by right clicking on the `node_modules` folder then `Mark directory as -> Not excluded`